# How do i collect static files in a django application deployed in digital ocean and store this in a staticfiles folder in AmazonS3 bucket?

Tags: python, django, docker, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I have a dockerized app deployed in digital ocean. However it fails to collect static files to be used in production. I have a static folder (static) containing the app's static files in django. I want to save the static files from the local static directory in a staticfiles folder in digital ocean.How can i solve this?

Attached is my settings.py in Django for storage settings.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = os.getenv("AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL")
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    "CacheControl": "max-age=86400",
}
AWS_LOCATION = "static"
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
# ]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"

# Media files
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (
    AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL,
    "media",
)  # Change this to a different path
# DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"

# Configuring Django to use DigitalOcean Spaces for media files
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /code

# Install build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata libpython3-dev gcc

# Upgrade pip and setuptools
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

# Copy requirements and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
# RUN pip install poetry
# RUN pip install django_cleanup
# RUN pip install import_export
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application files
COPY . .

# Collect static files
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

EXPOSE 8004
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8004"]
```

This fails at the static files stage when running the Dockerfile:

```
 => CACHED [web 4/8] RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools                                                                               0.0s
 => [web 5/8] COPY requirements.txt .                                                                                                       0.5s
 => [web 6/8] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                         330.8s
 => [web 7/8] COPY . .                                                                                                                     93.1s 
 => ERROR [web 8/8] RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput                                                                           24.6s 
------                                                                                                                                           
 > [web 8/8] RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput:                                                                                       
24.05 Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                         
24.05   File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in <module>                                                                                             
24.06     main()                                                                                                                                 
24.07   File "/code/manage.py", line 18, in main                                                                                                 
24.07     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

24.09     if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
24.09   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/storages/backends/s3.py", line 514, in exists
24.11     self.connection.meta.client.head_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=name)
24.11   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in _api_call
24.11     return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
24.11   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 946, in _make_api_call
24.12     api_params = self._emit_api_params(
24.12   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1072, in _emit_api_params
24.12     self.meta.events.emit(
24.12   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 412, in emit
24.12     return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
24.12   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 256, in emit
24.12     return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
24.12   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
24.12     response = handler(**kwargs)
24.12   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py", line 282, in validate_bucket_name
24.12     if not VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) and not VALID_S3_ARN.search(bucket):
24.12 TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python manage.py collectstatic --noinput" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Comment: Can you also include doc links here? There is plenty of documentation out there that helps you to solve this issue but we don't know where your source of information comes from. If you provide those links it will helpful for us to figure out what you may missed during the setup.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).